# Width 100%, margin auto and not working margin-bottom

Tags: html, css

This is probably really easy question, but I have no idea how to do this.
The width is set as 100%, and height is auto. I want to hide 200px from bottom, but `margin-bottom: -200px` is not working.

```css
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.banner-photo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.banner-photo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner-photo">
    <img src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/media/AAEAAQAAAAAAAANbAAAAJDE5NjBkNDk1LTY3ZGQtNDA0NS04YTJiLTdkNmU3NjZiNjI3Mg.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your end goal? I mean why don't you just make a smaller image if you don't want to show the bottom of it?

Comment: Is this the intended end result? --> https://jsfiddle.net/1g1w4L8m/2/ I'm not too sure if there is a particular element you are referring to because all elements have the styles you describe, also it doesn't look quite right. Could you provide an example of image of the intended end result?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a div like this, and it will effectively hide whatever is 200px from the bottom:

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;   
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the negative `margin-bottom` on your content (your `img`), and `overflow: hidden` on your container.

I've hidden 200px from your fiddle example - note that it doesn't leave much showing!

```css
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.banner-photo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner-photo img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner-photo">
    <img src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/media/AAEAAQAAAAAAAANbAAAAJDE5NjBkNDk1LTY3ZGQtNDA0NS04YTJiLTdkNmU3NjZiNjI3Mg.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```